# how to pip install from github for specific date

Tags: python, git, github

I need to install with pip from a git hub but wanted the repository from May 4th. Can anyone help me on that?

for instance if I want to `pip install` a repo's specific branch I can use below command :

```
pip install https://github.com/user/repo.git@branch
```

but don't know how get it by date other than branch name?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can replace `<branch>` with a desired commit `<sha-1>`. I've just checked it with bpython:

```
$ pip install --upgrade --user git+https://github.com/bpython/bpython.git@f2014dbae31313571cc9c26f51a14f4fda09d138
Collecting git+https://github.com/bpython/bpython.git@f2014dbae31313571cc9c26f51a14f4fda09d138
  Cloning https://github.com/bpython/bpython.git (to f2014dbae31313571cc9c26f51a14f4fda09d138) to /tmp/.private/alex/pip-tQcJmV-build
  Could not find a tag or branch 'f2014dbae31313571cc9c26f51a14f4fda09d138', assuming commit.
...
```

Another question is how to get a commit for a given date.

The first option is to open a browser, find an appropriate commit and manually form a proper URL for `pip install`. Actually I used this way for the example above.

But you may want to automate things. I would do a local shallow copy of a given repo from github:

```
git clone --depth 10 --single-branch --branch master https://github.com/bpython/bpython.git
```

(take only 10 last commits from master branch of `bpython` official repo)

Then, determine what commit satisfies the date restrictions:

```
COMMITID=$(git rev-list -n 1 --before '2016/04/07 16:36:15 2016 +0000' HEAD)
```

Then, use the commit id in the `pip install` command:

```
pip install --upgrade --user git+file:///tmp/.private/alex/bpython@${COMMITID}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could clone the repo, checkout the date you want locally and pip install in dev mode:

```
git clone https://github.com/user/repo.git
cd repo
git checkout `git rev-list -n 1 --before="2016-03-03 13:37" master`
pip install -e
```

Comment: Cheating! :) However, definitely +1

Comment: I'd honestly rely on the native pip mechanism of specifying the sha of the commit.

Comment: what's the difference? you have to clone the repo anyway to get the dates